# PHP/regex: matching/replacing 24-hour times

Tags: php, regex

How can I take a line like this:

Digital Presentation (10:45), (11:30), 12:00, 12:40, 13:20, 14:00, 14:40, 15:20, 16:00, 16:40, 17:20, 18:00, 18:40, 19:20, 20:00, 20:40, 21:20, 22:00, 22:40, 23:10, 23:40.

And match all the 24 hour times so I can convert to a more human readable format using date()?

Also I want to match times in the 24:00-24:59 range too

Thanks!

Comment: Please define "a more human readable format".

Comment: IMHO, it's a perfectly fine and human readable format already.

Comment: Are you sure about "24:00-24:59" range?

Shouldn't it be "23.00-23.59"? cause after that it should be "00.00-00.59" ??

Comment: 24:00—24:59 will be handled just fine by `strtotime` which would wrap the date/time around to the next day as appropriate

Answer (score 5):

You could use a regular expression like the following, which allows values from `00:00` through to `24:59` inclusive.

```
(?:[01][0-9]|2[0-4]):[0-5][0-9]
```

You seem to know what you're doing, so I'll only give a brief example without converting the times into date strings.

```
$times = array();
if (preg_match_all('/(?:[01][0-9]|2[0-4]):[0-5][0-9]/', $subject, $matches)) {
    $times = $matches[0];
}
print_r($times);
```

If the subject string has the chance of values like `1234:5678`, which would result in false positives with the above regex, then you could wrap the pattern in `\b` or some other assertion to make sure the time formatted numbers lie on their own.

Comment: @mr.b: `$matches[0]` contains the whole match for all of the items (it's `preg_match_all` after all)

Comment: I'm not sure why did I imagine that it was "foreach" instead of "if" in your code. but again, it wouldn't make any sense anyway. my bad, sorry. deleted my comment.

Comment: Should it be 23:59 as a max ?

Comment: What do you mean by wrap the pattern `\b` ? could you please add the fix for the false positive case?

Comment: @MehdiKaramosly re. 24:59, read the question. As for adding a "fix", no. Ask your own question if you must.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably easiest to match something like `(\d{2}):(\d{2})` (preg syntax), then convert both submatches to an integer and check whether they are in the correct range.

Comment: +1: Exactly right.  If $1 > 12, use ($1-12).'pm' else use "{$1}am".

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match_all('/([0-2][\d]):(\d{2})/', $string, $matches)
```

Now $matches[0] array contains all human readable times.

If you wish to print those along with specific date, feed each time through strtotime() function, like this

```
foreach ($matches[0] as $time) echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($time));
```

Comment: If you are using $matches[0] then no need for the grouping... /[0-2]\d:\d{2}/ would work fine for preg_match_all.

Comment: true. i have that habbit of grouping matches. and it's there in case he decides to use $matches[1] and $matches[2] arrays to access only hours or minutes, respectively, without having to split string by :